# How to resolve passing of same USER_ID for every post request in laravel JWT auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, vue.js, jwt

I am working with **Laravel, Vue.js** and I am currently using **JWT auth** for user authentication. I have implemented function for my buttons where I click the up button the vote increases and when I click the down it decreases but the problem is that if I switch user and login with another user I am still able do decrement another user's vote. The **user_id** in database is still the same and is not updated with new request. I am unable to find the problem please help as I am new to these technologies.

I have tried passing the id manually and then it works sometimes. I guess it is some problem with the authentication or my passing of user_id

this is my vote code:

```
public function vote(Request $request, $id) {

        $issue = Issue::findOrFail($id);
        $issueVotes = new \App\IssueVotes();
        $issueVotes->user_id = auth()->id();

        $issueVotes->issue_id = $request->issue_id;
            if($request->vote_type =='up') {

            $already_voted = \App\IssueVotes::where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('issue_id', $request->issue_id)->where('vote_type', $request->vote_type)->first();

            if(!$already_voted) {
                $issue->increment('votes');
                $issueVotes->vote_type = $request->vote_type;
                $issueVotes->save();
            }

        } elseif ($request->vote_type =='down') {

            $voted_up = \App\IssueVotes::where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('issue_id', $request->issue_id)->where('vote_type', 'up')->first();

            if($voted_up) {
                @$delete_down = \App\IssueVotes::where('user_id', auth()->id())->where('issue_id', $request->issue_id)->where('vote_type', 'up')->delete();
                $issue->decrement('votes');
            $issueVotes->vote_type = 'down';
                // $issueVotes->save();

            }

        }
        return response()->json($request->post_id, 200);
    }
```

And my JWT auth login code is:

```
public function login(Request $request)
        {

            $credentials = $request->json()->all();

            try{
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
                return response()->json(['error'=>'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            }
              }catch(JWTException $e) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500); // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            }

            return response()->json(compact('token'));

        }

        public function getAuthenticatedUser()
        {
            try{
                if(!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
                    return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
                }
            }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
                return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
                return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
                return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }

             return $user;
        }
```

What I am trying to achieve is that only the user who is logged in can change the vote value but of the posts on which he has given votes not on every post.

[Here is the screenshot of my database where I switched the user but the user_id remains the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOIjE.png)